# nth-child is not taking the element that´s needed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I got a document that is built like the following code:

```
<div id="menubox_container_box_body">
   <div class="categories">...</div>
   <div class="categories">
      <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
      <div class="cat_link">
          <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
               <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
               <div class="cat_sub_link">
                  <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
               </div>
                  <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
                  <div class="cat_sub_link">
               <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Now I am trying to select the a in the **first** `cat_link_container` with this command:

```
#menubox_categories_box_body .categories:nth-child(2) .cat_link .cat_link_container:nth-child(1){
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

What it does is giving ALL the `cat_link_container` elements (even the one's in the `cat_sub_link` div) a margin bottom. But I selected to only take the FIRST `cat_link_container` in `cat_link` and give it a `margin-bottom`. Someone has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: That is because all `cat_link_container` is the first child of its own parent.

Comment: that would mean there is no way to chose just the one i want?

Comment: You could use the `>` (children selector) in between `.cat_link` and `.cat_link_container` in the selector. I hope I understood your problem.

Comment: You´re a genius! Thank you very much. I didn´t think it´s so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select only the element with `class='cat_link_container'` under `div class='cat_link'` and not the elements with same class under its descendants, you need to make use of the `>` (children) selector like in the below code sample:

```css
#menubox_container_box_body .categories:nth-child(2) .cat_link > .cat_link_container:nth-child(1){
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubox_container_box_body">
    <div class="categories">...</div>
    <div class="categories">
        <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
        <div class="cat_link">
            <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation:

**Your original selector would be interpreted as follows:**

```
#menubox_container_box_body .categories:nth-child(2) .cat_link .cat_link_container:nth-child(1)
```

- Find the element with `id='menubox_container_box_body'`.
- Under this element, find all descendant elements (children, grand-children etc) which are the 2nd child of its parent and also has `class='categories'`.
- Under all the elements obtained in the previous point, find the element with `class='cat_link'`
- Traverse all elements which are fetched in above point, find all descendant elements which are the 1st child of its own parent and also has `class='cat_link_container'`.

```
<div id="menubox_container_box_body"> <!-- 1st point in explanation -->
    <div class="categories">...</div>
    <div class="categories"> <!-- 2nd point in explanation -->
        <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
        <div class="cat_link"> <!-- 3rd point in explanation --> 
            <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- descendant, first-child of its parent and so selected -->
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- descendant of the element referenced by 3rd point, first-child of its own parent and so selected -->
            </div>
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- descendant of the element referenced by 3rd point, first-child of its own parent and so selected -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**The revised selector that I have provided in answer will be interpreted as follows:**

```
#menubox_container_box_body .categories:nth-child(2) .cat_link > .cat_link_container:nth-child(1)
```

- Find the element with `id='menubox_container_box_body'`.
- Under this element, find all descendant elements (children, grand-children etc) which are the 2nd child of its parent and also has `class='categories'`.
- Under all the elements obtained in the previous point, find the element with `class='cat_link'`
- Traverse all elements which are fetched in above point, find the element which is the 1st child of its the element referred to by point 3 and also has `class='cat_link_container'`. Note how it checks only for direct child and not descendants.

```
<div id="menubox_container_box_body"> <!-- 1st point in explanation -->
    <div class="categories">...</div>
    <div class="categories"> <!-- 2nd point in explanation -->
        <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
        <div class="cat_link"> <!-- 3rd point in explanation --> 
            <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- direct child, first-child of its parent and so selected -->
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- not direct link and hence not selected -->
            </div>
            <div class="cat_icon">...</div>
            <div class="cat_sub_link">
                <div class="cat_link_container">...</div> <!-- not direct link and hence not selected -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```